# Map values in a list to a new value with PySpark

Tags: list, dictionary, pyspark, many-to-one

I'm trying to recode a list of values using Pyspark to create a new column.  I've set my mapping up with nested dictionaries, but can't get the mapping syntax figured out.  The original data has several string values that need to get recoded to a new value, then I want to give the column a new name.  The original column values will get grouped several different ways to create different new columns.

The df will have several thousand columns, so I need the code to be as efficient as possible.

I have a different scenario with a 1-1 mapping where I was able to create my expression with:

```
#expr = [ create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*values.items())])[orig_df[key]].cast(IntegerType()).alias('new_name') for key, values in my_dict.items() if key in orig_df.columns]
```

I just can't figure out the syntax for mapping the many to one.

Here's what I've tried:

```
grouping_dict = {'orig_col_n':{'new_col_n_a': {'20':['011','012'.'013'],'30':['014','015','016']},
    'new_col_n_b': {'25':['011','013','015'],'35':['012','014','016']}}}

expr = [ f.when(f.col(key) == f.lit(old_val),f.lit(new_value))
    .cast(IntegerType())
    .alias(new_var_name) 
    for key, new_var_names_dict in grouping_dict.items()
    for new_var_name,mapping_dict in new_var_names_dict.items()
    for new_value,old_value_list in mapping_dict.items()
    for  old_val in old_value_list 
    if key in original_df.columns]
                  

new_df = original_df.select(*expr)
```

This expression isn't quite right, it creates multiple columns with the same name as it loops through the values that need to be mapped.

Any suggestions for restructuring my dictionary or how to fix my syntax would be greatly appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocrz1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Eos.png)

orig_col_n  new_col_n_a new_col_n_b 
011                20     25
012                20     35
013                20     25
014                30     35
015                30     25
016                30     35

Comment: Can you update your question and include how your input and output data looks like ? This helps in better understanding

Comment: can you construct your dictionary to one1one and then you can easily apply this dictionary to rdd